# Showing/splitting data on a single report page

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm unsure at this point how to present the problem I'm having developing a requested report with SSRS. The db View that I've been given to work with, along with the requested formatting of the report itself, are static so I'm restricted as far as what I can do (although I may be able to get the View changed or a SP added, if needed). The View data is as shown below.

'Short'-ish version of my problem - the View has Sales information for two types of sales 
(normal and discounted, apparently?). The requested format of the report is to have each Rep's sales on separate pages of the report, and have separate displays of each type of sale, i.e. RepName at top of page, with two different tables showing Sale and DiscountedSale information separately. I have a report created for both types, but when I try to add the DiscSale report as a SubReport to the Sale report, I get the expected problems. I have no known way to ensure that the data being used for both on a page are for the same SalesRep and don't know how to determine the unique datapoint (RepFullName) for each page. Even if I did I don't know how to create that relationship in SSRS. I haven't even brought up what I know will be a 'future issue' for this - all SalesReps do NOT have available records 
for both types of Sales, so I don't know how to account for a linked report (Main or Sub) that returns no records without that in turn impacting the User records after that.

I apologize if the description of my problem sounds cryptic or muddled, but that's how my brain is currently functioning and dealing with this, to be honest! If anyone can understand what my problems are and be able to point me in the right direction for resolving this I'd be greatly appreciative!

Available View Fields
 DayOfCharge, RepFullName, ManagerFullName, ChargeNumber, ProductID, SaleStart, SaleEnd, SaleTime, DiscStart, DiscEnd, DiscTime, ProductName, Description

Thank You!!

Patrick

Comment: It seems that your reports have already been developed, in which case this may not be of any assistance. If you render a matrix grouped by sales rep. You can embed matrixes in the 'salesrep' detail that tie into the 'sales' details with further grouping. Then optionally show the lines with the sub-matrixes having data.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating a subreport, you could return both the regular sales and discounted sales in the same data set. You can then add two different data regions to the report (I assume you will be using tables) and add a filter to each to only show either sales or discounted sales.

If you put both these tables inside a List region, and you data set has one row per sales rep then you should be able to display one page per sales rep with two tables, one for sales and one for discounted sales.